# Angular Send params as a variable key and value

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add categories key and value like jumia as params
[https://www.jumia.com.eg/baby-diapering/-insular--bluelans--dimooo--generic/?price_discount=30-100&seller_score=4-5&color_family=Beige--Black][1]
how to make it and add new checked like this

Comment: I don't understand your question. When do you like to add parameters? Are you using the Angular HttpClient? Do you want to add query string parameters for an HTTP request? Or what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I want to add query according to checkbox add key and value that checked as queryparams like color_family=Beige--Black and add more than value according key

Answer (score 0):

You can have a object containing items selected from a checkbox.

```
let checkedItems = {price_discount : 30, seller_score: 30, color_family: 'Beige--Black'};
```

Iterate over the object and create a query param string.

```
let queryParams = "?";
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(checkedItems)){
    queryParams  = queryParams + key + "=" + value + "&";
}
```

Then add query params to the URL.

```
let URL = 'https://www.jumia.com.eg/baby-diapering/-insular--bluelans--dimooo--generic/' + queryParams;
```

Now, in variable URL you will have all query params added.

Comment: it also worth wrapping `value` into `encodeURIComponent(value)` to escape special characters. But also you can use HttpParams from @angular/common/http - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams